# How can I share my private keys between my host and guest machines?

Tags: ssh, vagrant

When committing my code into Git, I need SSH keys that I've previously registered as my own. Currently, I have to add my local `~/.ssh`, and then go ahead and add the one in the guest's `~/.ssh` as well, so that I can commit from both my host and my guest.

Is there a way to simplify this workflow? Setting my `~/.ssh` as a synced folder doesn't work since the file permissions are `0777` instead of `0600`.

Comment: Why you want to use git on your host and your guest ?

Answer (score 0):

Use ssh-copy-id

```
ssh-copy-id user@remotehost
```

or copy it

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@remotehost "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```